# DS9 configuration issue

Tags: data-analysis, astronomy, exploratory-data-analysis, x-ray, ds9

I'm trying to use DS9 for X-ray image analysis. Before that I have to configure it for use, I need to click on option using web proxy[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aeeP.png)

Beside use internal web browser checkbox there should be another checkbox with name using web proxy that I have to check in to use this software specifically.

I using windows 11.
can anyone help me with this?

I tried to configure my system for proxy
control pannel>Network and Internet>Internet Options>Connections>Lan settings
then checked in at use a proxy server for your LAN